# Filter report by StartDate and EndDate

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress

I want to create filter which will filter my report by `StartDate` and `EndDate`. 
So far I have create in WebForm `ComboBox` which containt type of `Reports` and when I choose report and choose `StartDate: 05-01-2020` `EndDate : 05-31-2020` it needs to display in report only record which is in this period of time.

```
        public void BindToData()
        {

            modGlobal global = new modGlobal();
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DesignSaoOsig1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {

                string strProc = "TestReport";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter comand = new SqlDataAdapter(strProc, myConnection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", orgUnitId.ToString().Trim());

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strProc))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    comand.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    cmd.Connection = myConnection;

                    if (myDataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        myConnection.Close();
                    }

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
                    report.DataSource = myDataSet;                  

                }
            }
        }
```

So far here is my function which I need to complete, I stuck and have no ideas how to complete this.

Comment: I assume you're worked this out now judging by your next question?

Comment: Yes, this is old one. I will delete this post.